# EntityFrameWork model relationship configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm coding in ef 5 code first solution and i have a model as follow:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get;set;}

   public int Role1Id {get; set;}
   public Role Role1 {get; set;}
}
```

and another model:

```
public class Role
{
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

also i configure this model in another class as follow:

```
  public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public UserConfig()
        {
            ToTable("User", "dbo");
            // Here i want introduce Role1 as navigation property for Role1Id property
        }
    }
```

here is the question:How can i config User model to introduce Role1 as navigation property for Role1Id property?

Comment: Are you writing this code yourself? Entity Framework can create this plumbing code itself.

Comment: I'm using ef code first,so i have to code my models first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotation:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get;set;}

   public int Role1Id {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("Role1Id")]
   public Role Role1 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: yes that works but i want to config my model in my UserConfig class(via entity model configuration).

Answer (score 0):

EF should configure it automatically as long as the id matches the field generated in the database schema.

You could try to configure it in UserConfig with the following:

```
HasRequired(user => user.Role1)
   .WithRequiredDependent()
   .Map(mapping => mapping.MapKey("Role1Id");
```

This configures it to be required. You can use the HasOption method if it's not required as well.